# Delete redundant suffix or move it to another column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table like this

```
-----------------------------------
| id |  col_name  |  colname_suf  |
-----------------------------------
| 1  | textSuff_ix| null          |
| 2  | strSuff_ix2| null          |
|  ...                            |
-----------------------------------
```

The main idea of my solution is to move suffix to another column. But suffix and text before can be in known range(text1, text2, str, Suff_ix1, Suff_ix2, Suff_ix3...). How i can fix it using sql query?

Comment: what would be the desired output of the example above?

Comment: Which `DBMS` are you using?

Comment: Arun Palanisamy, ms sql server 2014

Comment: @zip , col_name should keep text without suffix and suffix should move to colname_suf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use string functions like `left()`, `right()` and `charindex()` to split the column and update:

```
update tablename
set [col_name] = left([col_name], charindex('_', [col_name]) - 1),
    [colname_suf] = right([col_name], len([col_name]) - charindex('_', [col_name]))
where [col_name] like '%[_]%';
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e8daf0afbb3e1c5c4813cdb1e742b55b).
Results:

```
> id | col_name | colname_suf
> -: | :------- | :----------
>  1 | textSuff | ix         
>  2 | strSuff  | ix2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use string operations:

```
select left(col_name, charindex('_', col_name) - 1) as prefix,
       stuff(col_name, 1, charindex('_', col_name), '') as suffix
```